# Plotly JS - Stacked bar width and y axis height

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm currently trying to have a thinner bar in a stacked bar graph with a y axis range that doesnt take as much room as it does (see codepen example : https://codepen.io/arckauss/pen/VwGPaXj)

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: [20, 14, 23],
  y: ['giraffes'],
  orientation: 'h'
}];

var layout = {
  autosize: true,
  margin: {
    l: 1,
    r: 1,
    b: 1,
    t: 1,
  },
  bargroupgap: 0.95,
  barmode: 'stack',
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

As you can see in the example, the y axis is taking a lot of space above and beneath the bar. I would like to reduce this space and ideally only show the bar without any "margin".

I have tried with the bar width in the traces, bargroupgap and bargap but no success at the moment. Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Thx @Yogi, but this doesnt help since it will change the size of the whole graph instead of the "range" of the y axis. Updated codepen for more clarity

Comment: @Yogi is right, it seems what you want is to set a small `height` to the layout, which will reduce the height of the graph yes, but you can increase the top/bottom margin accordingly to compensate : the default margin is 80, let say the graph looks fine with `height: 200`, then you would adjust the margin by setting `margin: {t: 80 + x, b: 80 + x}` with `x` an arbitrary value. The range of the yaxis can't be reduced, this is a categorical axis and there is one item so the range is already `[0, 0]`, and anyway reducing the axis range amounts to zooming, which doesn't change the graph size.